# Does exist a way to verify with ArchUnit that any method doesn´t throw any exception?

Tags: archunit

I would like to know if exist a way in ArchUnit to avoid that the signature of a method throws any checked exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access a code unit's declared exceptions via [`JavaMethod.getThrowsClause()`](https://javadoc.io/doc/com.tngtech.archunit/archunit/latest/com/tngtech/archunit/core/domain/JavaMethod.html#getThrowsClause()) (or [`JavaConstructor.getThrowsClause()`](https://javadoc.io/doc/com.tngtech.archunit/archunit/latest/com/tngtech/archunit/core/domain/JavaConstructor.html#getThrowsClause()), respectively).

The following rule using a [custom condition](https://www.archunit.org/userguide/html/000_Index.html#_creating_custom_rules) forbids the declaration of any exceptions – you can easily adapt it to your needs if you want to exclude `RuntimeException`s:

```java
@ArchTest
static ArchRule no_code_units_should_declare_exceptions = noCodeUnits()
    .should(new ArchCondition<JavaCodeUnit>("declare exceptions") {
       @Override
       public void check(JavaCodeUnit codeUnit, ConditionEvents events) {
         int nThrowsDeclarations = codeUnit.getThrowsClause().size();
         String message = String.format("%s has %d throws declarations in %s",
             codeUnit.getDescription(), nThrowsDeclarations, codeUnit.getSourceCodeLocation()
         );
         events.add(new SimpleConditionEvent(codeUnit, nThrowsDeclarations > 0, message));
       }
    });
```

Comment: Yep, using this way, you can review that option in any package or in the whole module.  @AnalyzeClasses(packages = "com.jab.microservices", importOptions = {ImportOption.DoNotIncludeTests.class})